# How to always remove WWW from a url with mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following to try and remove WWW from the url:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com$1 [R=301]
```

But for some reason it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here’s a more generalized solution:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Is there a way to detect and rewrite to the same URL scheme (http or https) from which a user came? `http://www.example.com/` to `http://example.com/` and `https://www.example.com/` to `https://example.com`.

Comment: Does the REQUEST_URI contain index.php? For some reason when I go www.example.com, it redirects to www.example.com/index.php

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Don't forget the QSA flag if you want to append the original query string.

Answer (score 28):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And without `mod_rewrite`:

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.1:80>
        ServerName www.example.com
        Redirect permanent / http://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Virtual hosts can be used by completing the steps in the following URL: [Setting Up A Virtual Host in Apache](http://apptools.com/phptools/virtualhost.php).

Comment: This is what happened: The webpage at http://www.example.com/ has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer. *I removed these but the site is still down! Why so??*

Comment: Question 1. Did you use both at the same time? Question 2. Did you change the IP address to the correct value? Question 3. Do you own example.com?

Comment: +1 for virtualhost approach. Don't resort to mod_rewrite until you really need to.

Comment: Ans 1: Yes. I've removed both now and the site's up. Ans 2: I have no clue where to add/remove virtualhost. Ans 3: I'm using example.com instead of my website. Can you pls tell me more about virtualhost and where can I make the change? I have no clue.. been only using mod_rewrite.

Comment: Great, I've edited in th virtual host stuff as well if you need it.

Comment: I suggest you remove the "10.0.0.1" bit by "*" for a more portable solution.

Comment: is the `QSA` flag necessary since theres `$1`? my understanding is that the `1` refers to whatever query string might be present?

Answer (score 10):

As a minor tweak of Kyle's answer, I'd put a / in the RewriteRule match condition, like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Otherwise, you get a double slash as a result.

```
http://www.example.com/smth -> http://example.com//smth
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

I would always use 307 (temporary redirect) first because if you get it wrong some browsers cache it permanently. I ended up installing Google Chrome just because I couldn't get my Firefox to forget a bad redirect even when I deleted the whole cache.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution if you don't want a hard coded domain name.  Don't forget to start the rewrite engine or this won't work!

```
 # Start rewrite engine
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine On
 </IfModule>

 # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>
```