# Remove “www” from website link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, web

So, I have a rails project deployed using apache server. Unfortunately, the domain name is not registered with www. So if I do `https://mydoin.com` it works but `https://www.mydoin.com` doesn't. Now what I need is that, if someone uses this URL with www `https://www.mydoin.com` then I want to remove www from the URL. How can I do this? I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and apache 2.4.

Comment: You need to create an 'A' record with hostname 'www' and point it to '@' record which is already pointing to your server.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to register the www.mydoin.com DNS, without this, your server will not be reached by your user. After this, you can configure a redirect in your server or rewrite your requisition, for this, follow this link: [How to always remove WWW from a url with mod_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361499/how-to-always-remove-www-from-a-url-with-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

This code will auto strip the www. for you even if its a subdomain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

If you want to fix you DNS issue just add a 'A' record with www.yourwebsite.com